# How to get multiple formattings of a row's values into multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
TableA.ColumnA
1000
2100
5435
```

I need to pull this data with multiple formats for each number on their own row like this:

```
Results
1,000
1000.00
1,000.00
2,100
2100.00
2,100.00
5,435
5435.00
5,435.00
```

I am aware of how to write a select statement to get them each in their own column and formatted the way I want. However, I would like to have them all in one straight column like this and I don't know how. Thank you for any help!

Comment: This should not be done in sql. It should be done in the front end. If you really must do this you can use UNION with each query having their own format.

Comment: What version of SS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to so this (assuming you are using 2014+). The formats are not exactly what you showed but then your formats are a bit strange.

```
with something as
(
    select 1000 as SomeValue union all
    select 2100 union all
    select 5435
)

select x.Value
from something
cross apply 
(
    values (FORMAT(SomeValue, 'N', 'en-us'))
        ,(FORMAT(SomeValue, 'G', 'en-us'))
        ,(FORMAT(SomeValue, 'C', 'en-us'))
) x(Value)
```

Comment: Ahh yes...FORMAT was introduced in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work so well in SQL Server 2008. When you add a comma, the field has to be a `varchar`, so to get all of your output in the same column, they all have to be `varchar`.

I used Sean's example and modified a bit.

1. Incorporates `UNPIVOT`
2. Should work for earlier versions of SQL Server where `FORMAT` is unavailable

(I put the 3 values in a temp table called #Temp)

```
;with something as
(
    select CONVERT(varchar,Value) Value
         , CONVERT(varchar,cast(Value as money)) Value2
         , CONVERT(varchar, cast(value as money),1) Value3
    from #temp
)

select myVal as Value
from something
unpivot
(myVal for val in (Value, Value2, Value3)) p
```

Comment: Thank you, rwking. I had no idea about the unpivot command. That's great to know!

Comment: You can use the cross apply instead of UNPIVOT in 2008. The only part of my code that won't work in 2008 is FORMAT because it didn't exist until 2012. Nonetheless this is nice.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean to suggest cross apply isn't available in '08. Just providing an alternate method. Thanks!